# Invalid content was found starting with element 'elementName'. No child element is expected at this point

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm working with xml and I'm using xsd to validate my xml file. My xsd and xml file is too long and I can give you a part of them.

**XSD file:**

```
...
<xs:complexType name="BankType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="Code" type="codeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="NewCode" type="codeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="SWIFTBIC" type="swiftType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Name" type="nameType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="CorAccount" type="accountType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="SubCorAccount" type="accountType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="TaxNumber" type="taxNumberType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Address" type="addressType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="PhoneNumber" type="phoneNoType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="FaxNumber" type="faxNumberType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="OperationsForBankType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Method" type="methodType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Bank" type="BankType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
...
```

**XML file:**

```
...
<Operations>
  <Method>ADD</Method>
  <Bank>
    <Code>111111</Code>
    <SWIFTBIC>AAAAAAAA</SWIFTBIC>
    <Name>ASDFGHJKL</Name>
    <CorAccount>1111111111111111111111111111</CorAccount>
    <SubCorAccount>1111111111111111111111111111</SubCorAccount>
    <TaxNumber>1700792251</TaxNumber>
    <Address>Bakı şəhəri, Nizami küçəsi, 70</Address>
    <PhoneNumber>+994125981107</PhoneNumber>
    <FaxNumber>+994125980307</FaxNumber>
  </Bank>
  ...
```

And the error was `Reason: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'SWIFTBIC'. No child element is expected at this point.` How can I solve it?

**EDIT:** I used `xs:sequence` before but the order of tags might be changeable that's why I couldnot use it. All elements can be occur, can be empty, can be doesn't occur..

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your `xsd` all elements are expected.

**Choice Indicator**

The  indicator specifies that either one child element or another can occur:

**Sequence Indicator**

The  indicator specifies that the child elements must appear in a specific order:

try this:-

```
<xs:complexType name="BankType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Code" type="codeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="NewCode" type="codeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="SWIFTBIC" type="swiftType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Name" type="nameType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="CorAccount" type="accountType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="SubCorAccount" type="accountType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="TaxNumber" type="taxNumberType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Address" type="addressType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="PhoneNumber" type="phoneNoType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="FaxNumber" type="faxNumberType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: @kamal can you post the definition of your swiftType element ?

Comment: `<xs:simpleType name="swiftType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9]{0}|[A-Z0-9]{8}" />
   <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>` This error is not based on `swiftType` because I deleted this row from xml and after this I get the same error for `name` element.

Comment: Ok. @kamal
Just a guess did you try changing the order for this.
<xs:element name="SWIFTBIC" type="swiftType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
instead of putting after NewCode put it some where else(just a random thought).
P.s. As i can see it shouldn't give any issues.

Comment: I changed the order of `swiftType` and got the same error for `name` and after this I changed the order of `nameType` and got the same error for `corraccount` etc. After this I deleted all rows in `<Bank>` from xml except `<Code>` and didnt get any error.

Comment: Then I doubt your IDE(eclipse or Jdeveloper or whatever you are usingetc..). Just do crtl+A-->crtl+x-->crtl+s --> crtl+v--> crtl+s.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46900/discussion-between-kamal-and-saurabh-sharma)

Answer (score 0):

Change complexType BankType into an `xs:all` instead of an xs:choice. But you can't have `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in an `xs:all` so you need to limit phone and fax numbers to max. 1 or you need to create a container element (PhoneNumbers etc.) that can contain multiple numbers but of which you can have a maximum of 1.

Comment: I cannot use `xs:sequence` because the order of tags may be changable

Comment: I can't change xml file. I can change only my xsd file and to appropriate for xml

Comment: If you want to have a random allowed order and more than one occurrence of PhoneNumber, then this is not possible to define in an XML schema 1.0 compliant schema. However in XML schema 1.1 this restriction was removed and you can change your xs:choice into an xs:all and it will do exactly what you want

Comment: There are a few XML schema 1.1 validators written in Java: Saxon (only the paid commercial version) and Xerces (still in beta)